# Can't export xlsx or xls in proper format all data are jumbled

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel excel library "maatwebsite/excel"

Here is my code

```
\Excel::create('Users Report' . $time, function ($excel) use ($arrUsers) {


                $excel->sheet('Users', function ($sheet) use ($arrUsers) {

                    // Set all margins
                    $sheet->fromArray($arrUsers, null, 'A1', true);

                    $sheet->setSize('A1', 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('B1', 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('C1', 25, 18);


                    $sheet->row(1, array(
                        'Id', 'Name', 'Username', 'Address', 'Email'
                    ));

                    // Freeze first row
                    $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
                    $sheet->cell('A1:F1', function ($cell) {
                    });

                });
            })->store('xlsx')->download('xlsx');
```

File is downloaded successfully but when I try to open is shown like follows

[image]

I refer following sites and tried according to his solutions but didn't get any solution.
 https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/202

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem in output buffer solved by

```
   ob_end_clean();

    ob_start(); //At the very top of your program (first line)

    \Excel::create('Users Report' . $time, function ($excel) use ($arrUsers) {


                    $excel->sheet('Users', function ($sheet) use ($arrUsers) {

                        // Set all margins
                        $sheet->fromArray($arrUsers, null, 'A1', true);

                        $sheet->setSize('A1', 25, 18);
                        $sheet->setSize('B1', 25, 18);
                        $sheet->setSize('C1', 25, 18);


                        $sheet->row(1, array(
                            'Id', 'Name', 'Username', 'Address', 'Email'
                        ));

                        // Freeze first row
                        $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
                        $sheet->cell('A1:F1', function ($cell) {
                        });

                    });

                })->store('xlsx')->download('xlsx');

    ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when your code sends any warning or errror to the screen, try [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), in order to see if your program send any character to the output:

```
<?php
ob_start(); //At the very top of your program (first line)

\Excel::create('Users Report' . $time, function ($excel) use ($arrUsers) {


                $excel->sheet('Users', function ($sheet) use ($arrUsers) {

                    // Set all margins
                    $sheet->fromArray($arrUsers, null, 'A1', true);

                    $sheet->setSize('A1', 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('B1', 25, 18);
                    $sheet->setSize('C1', 25, 18);


                    $sheet->row(1, array(
                        'Id', 'Name', 'Username', 'Address', 'Email'
                    ));

                    // Freeze first row
                    $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
                    $sheet->cell('A1:F1', function ($cell) {
                    });

                });

            })->store('xlsx')->download('xlsx');

//Catch any character sended to the output at this point
$out = ob_get_contents();

//Routing the output to the error_log
error_log($out);                

//Cleaning the ouput buffer
ob_end_clean();
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks Omecoati, it's very helpful for me, Your answer are 95% correct, I am giving correct answer below.