# laravel.log is populated with errors, error screen is blank

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm developing on Laravel 5.4.  laravel.log is working perfectly fine, but when I experience an error, the user screen is white. When the screen is white if I view source, I see a bunch of html....

Also, when I add dd() to my code, the screen is also white, but if I do view source I can see what is supposed to appear.

Would like to see the errors normally on screen.  It did work at some point, and I haven't done any upgrades to Laravel or MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

ob_end_clean(); 
ob_start();

at the top of one of my controllers and now the errors are properly appearing instead of a white page. I wasn't trying to fix this error but it came as a by product of trying to clean up some excel export issues.  More info at this link

[Can't export xlsx or xls in proper format all data are jumbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692749/cant-export-xlsx-or-xls-in-proper-format-all-data-are-jumbled)

Comment: Also per the instructions, I later went back and removed anything before the first  <?php in my files

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that you're using PHP shorthand opening tags? `<? ?>` and not `<?PHP ?>`

You can also try converting your code to HTML entities:

```
dd(htmlentities($errors));
```

If that does show the code then it means there's something in your errors itself that's causing this behavior.

Alternatively try:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: Wherever I added php code I did use <?PHP ?> already. "php artisan optimize" I tried unsuccessfully when researching the problem and before posting this question.

Comment: Not yet as this solution will not do anything for error scenarios, which is the main problem.  I just mentioned the dd thing as extra information to help determine what might be the actual problem.  I am going to try Laravel Debugbar to see if this helps.  I'm also seeing in 5.5. that Whoops is coming back, so that upgrade may help as well.

Comment: Debugbar works, but the screen still turns white when there is an error.

Comment: Havd you tried clearing view cache? ``php artican view:clear`` Also ave a go with different browser too.

Comment: Neither is helping unfortunately.

Comment: last sample from log

Comment: [2017-07-19 08:09:47] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\edhir_000\GoogleDrive\laragon\www\readysetgig\app\Http\Controllers\ContactController.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\edhir_000\GoogleDrive\laragon\www\readysetgig\app\Http\Controllers\ContactController.php(29): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\\Users\\edhir_...', 29, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ContactController->index()
#2 
etc.

Comment: Seems the issue is just the onscreen rendering...the content is there.